# Select all fields value where all fileds value like some String

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate

can someone help, i need to get all values from fields where all fields values like %someString%. My table have 17 fields, i don't want write all fields in query. DB Mysql.

```
select * from Deputes_APPEAL where filePath, checkForPlagiarism, contentOfResolution, countOfPages, dateForCheck, incomeNumber, incomingDate, mainWorker, nameAndAddressOfApplicant, nameOfDepute, outDate, outNumber, result, secondaryWorkers, shortContentOfAppeal, statusOfWorking, themeOfAppeal, TypeOfDeputeAppeal, unitWhoDoResolution like %someString%
```

Comment: Writing the 17 fields in the query would have taken less time than posting this question.

Comment: maybe, but this doesn't like correctly?

Comment: Post your table structure and also mention which fields you want to omit from the `LIKE `clause.

Comment: `select * from Deputes_APPEAL where filePath like '%someString%' or checkForPlagiarism like '%someString%' or ...`: that will find all rows where at least one field is like %someString%. If they should all be like %someString%, then use and rather than or.

Comment: i can write select * from Deputes_APPEAL where concat (all fields) like %someString%, sql has universal clause for it ? i don't want list all fields in query

Comment: You can, but that won't do the same things. Example: filePath is 'foo', checkForPlagiarism is 'bar', and you're searching for 'foobar'. None of the fields is like foobar, but their concatenation is.

Answer (score 0):

One way you can achieve this would be the following:

```
SELECT 
CONCAT('SELECT * FROM Deputes_APPEAL WHERE ',GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME SEPARATOR ' LIKE \'%something%\' OR '),' LIKE \'%something%\'')
FROM information_schema.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'YOUR_DATABASE_NAME'
AND TABLE_NAME = 'YOUR_TABLE_NAME'
AND COLUMN_NAME NOT IN ('Column1','Column2',....);
```

**Note:** You need to put the column names inside the `NOT IN` clause those you want to omit in `LIKE` expression.

**Output:** By running the above query you will get an output like below:

`SELECT * FROM Deputes_APPEAL WHERE column_name1 LIKE '%something%' OR .......`

Now grab this query and run.

Answer (score 0):

Just build the SQL using loops - super simple.

```
final String[] properties = new String[] { /* all your fields here */ };

// build the SQL
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append( "SELECT o FROM YourEntity o " );
if ( properties.length > 0 ) {
  sb.append( "WHERE ( " ).append( properties[0] ).append( "LIKE :v0" );
  for ( int i = 1; i < properties.length; ++i ) {
    sb.append( " OR " ).append( properties[i] ).append( "LIKE :v" ).append(i); 
  }
  sb.append( " ) " );
}

// build the query.
Query query = session.createQuery( sb.toString() );
for ( int i = 0; i < properties.length; ++i ) {
  query.setParameter( "v" + i, "%something%" );
}
```